# Spring boot cannot resolve property placeholder within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm running currently in a strange problem when starting a spring boot (2.3) application from within eclipse (2020-06, jdk 8). The project (maven based) has a dependency that contains a service and a yml file. This yml defines a property like ${something}. *something* is defined in turn in the yml of my project.
So far so good. When I start the project, spring cannot instantiate the service mentioned above because it cannot resolve *something*
When I create a runnable jar with maven and start it in a termninal, the applications runs perfectly.
Any help appreciated
TIA Kibu

Comment: Your Eclipse is two releases behind. Do you have Spring Tools installed? When and how will the property resolved? When it will be resolved on compile time by the Maven build, I guess, you have to specify the property in your run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Java launcher, try recreating it using a "Run as" -> "Java Application". This solved the issue for me.